# How to change app window via button in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

So I'm trying to do my first UWP app with controls and different pages, I have done the MVVM for it and I want to initialize new page with one of my buttons, how can I do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So I have this and I want to initialize new window which is called AddingMatchView through the AddMatch function  


 internal class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {

        }

        public void AddMatch()
        {
            //here I want to start new window(it's a click action for button on XAML, I have binded it
        }
    }

Comment: Could you please be more specific about your question? What's the behavior that you want to get and what have you tried now? Please update your question and tell us what you've done and what's the problem. You could also share your code snippet there.